# Derivative of complex root

Tags: complex-analysis

Suppose we fix the branch definided in $\mathbb{C}-(\infty,0]$ and that satisfies $f(1)=-i $ for $f(z)=z^{1/4}$. 
We are asked to compute $f'(e^{i 2\pi/3})$.

The derivative es $f'(z)=\frac{1}{4} z^{-3/4}$ , where we calculate the root in the same branch as in $f$.

If I calculate $1/4 \frac{1}{(e^{i 2\pi/3})^{3})^{1/4}}$ I get $i/4$. On the other hand if I calculate $1/4 \frac{1}{(e^{i 2\pi/3})^{1/4})^{3}}$ I get $-1/4$.
I don't know which one is the correct solution, and why...

Comment: Both should give the same result (I think), but you need to pay attention to the branch. That means the argument should be in $(-3\pi,-\pi)$. (Assuming that you meant $e^{i2\pi/3}$)

Comment: Sorry, of course, I meant $e^{ i 2 \pi /3}$.

Comment: If I calculate $(e^{i 2\pi /3})^{1/4}$, I get $e^{i 5 \pi /3}$ (in that branch). Therefore when a do the cube, I don't get the same.. I am confused.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sorry, I think I made a mistake in my comment. You can get the correct result by not separating the numerator and denominator. $$z^{-3/4}=(e^{-4i\pi/3})^{-3/4}=e^{(-3/4)(-4i\pi/3)}=e^{i\pi}=-1$$

You can also get this result by using $$z^{-3/4}=\frac{z^{1/4}}{z}= \frac{(e^{2i\pi/3})^{1/4}}{e^{2i\pi/3}}=\frac{(e^{-4i\pi/3})^{1/4}}{e^{2i\pi/3}}=\frac{e^{-i\pi/3}}{e^{2i\pi/3}}=-1 $$

Both these methods have the advantage of giving the correct answer when you're not dealing with rational exponents. You can't choose between $(z^p)^{1/q}$ and $(z^{1/q})^p$ when you have $\sqrt2$ instead of $3/4$, for example.